# Минусы использования JSON-файлов вместо базы данных

Tags: python, json, оптимизация

Я бы хотел точнее углубиться в эту тему и понять - плохо ли хранение всей информации напрямую в json-файлах на hdd.

Знаю, что многие используют sqlite3 - возможно, что она проще в реализации. Но какие еще есть *подводные камни?*

Comment: неизвестны ваши задачи, из-за этого нельзя назвать ни плюсы, ни минусы. Пишите код так, чтобы в любой момент можно было заменить хранение в файле на хранение в БД

Comment: хранение/редактирование/получение данных

Comment: ваш комментарий никак не проясняет ваших целей и задач

Comment: что делают с базой данных? хранят в ней информацию, я также поступаю и с json файлами - просто создаю их для каждого пользователя отдельно, заполняю его, затем считываю оттуда информацию для своих нужно и иногда редактирую

Comment: Какая информация? Какие объемы? Как потом используете? Для чего?

Comment: Ну вот представьте что у вас в файле миллион записей, а вам на экран нужно показать 10 записей. При этом они хаотично разбросаны по файлу, У БД есть индексы из бинарных деревьев и несколько алгоритмов поисков. А что есть у вас кроме json файла?

Comment: Мои проекты слишком малы для таких объемов. Я храню на каждого пользователя до 10 переменных - мне большего и не нужно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У каждого подхода есть свои плюсы и минусы. Опишу то, чего нет у другого подхода.

JSON: это текстовый файл, так что это просто.

- легко можно из любого текстового редактора изменить данные
- не надо писать дополнительный код для соединения с бд и запросам к ней
- легко можено передать файл другому человеку, а тот без труда начнёт с ним работать
- не надо извращаться с хранением массивов/словарей, структуры данных есть по умолчанию

SQLite: это одно из полноценных субд, которые появились, когда людям стало не хватать текстовых файликов.

- данные структурированы
- если у вас несколько гигабайт данных, то считать пару значений будет во много раз быстрее, чем с .json.
- дозалить и измененить также во много раз быстрее (не надо считывать и записывать каждый раз весь файл, только пару байтов)
- встроенные проверки на типы данных

Если вам надо просто записать сколько-то данных и хранить их как архив, то json может показать себя с лучшей стороны, но если вам вести какой-то учёт этих данных и активно работать с ними, то добро пожаловать в мир sqlite.

Comment: Именно такой ответ я и хотел услышать. Спасибо Вам.

Comment: Про встроенные проверки типов это вы немного переборщили, конкретно в sqlite это реализовано очень своеобразно. Вы можете сохранить строку в поле `integer` и вообще вот из документации цитата `Any column in an SQLite version 3 database, except an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column, may be used to store a value of any storage class.`

Answer (score 4):

Еще важное отличие - это поддержка транзакций в БД.

Может показаться, что вам это не важно, т.к. вы транзакции, возможно, не используете. Но тут есть одно важное и неочевидное следствие и различие в работе с файлами и БД.

В БД после выполнения успешной фиксации операций изменения (commit) вы можете быть уверены, что данные сохранены. При работе с файлами это не так.

Программа может сохранить данные в файл, закрыть его и сообщить пользователю, что операция завершилась успешно. Но если в этот момент произойдет программный или аппаратный сбой (например, ошибка в драйвере, которая приводит к перезагрузке ОС или выключение питания на компьютере без ИБП), то есть немалая вероятность, что данные еще не успели из дискового кеша ОС сохраниться на диск.

После перезагрузки данные могут быть утеряны. И при работе с файлами это нужно учитывать. БД так устроены, что они заботятся о том, чтоб после `commit` данные гарантированно были сохранены.

Comment: [man fsync](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fsync.2.html), в общем-то именно это использует  СУБД для гарантий записи на носитель

Comment: fsync это один из методов. Я знаю только, как в postrgres (но думаю в других так же) - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-WAL-SYNC-METHOD тут все опции перечислены. Это нужно настраивать в зависимости от того что за ОС/файловая система/контроллер диска используется.