# Где лучше хранить массив объектов? json или бд?

Tags: javascript, sql, json, mongodb

Впервые тут спрашиваю. Тесть попросил реализовать журнал приема-сдачи электроскутеров с мобильных телефонов. Я еще учусь на frontend направлении, но в целом задачу осилю.

Собственно дилемма. Есть около 1000 электроскутеров для курьеров и нужен базовый мониторинг использования данных скутеров. Думал написать небольшой фронт с формой, который будет тянуть какой то json с массивом объектов, в котором и будут эти скутеры, ну и для сохранения истории использования скутеров курьерами думал загуглить как нодой писать изменения в данный json.

Но подскажите стоит ли для данной задачи использовать именно json или лучше изучить как это все писать в полноценную БД? Ну и если БД, то какую выбрать?

Никакого сесюрити тут не нужно, данные будут обезличены, просто массив объектов с числовыми значениями, булевыми да несколькими стрингами.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Минусы использования JSON-файлов вместо базы данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1316631/%d0%9c%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-json-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Answer (score 1):

Если хранить в json - то при параллельном доступе может возникнуть много тонкостей.

А параллельный доступ - это естественное состояние для web - приложений

так что - советую сразу использовать базу...

Comment: Собственно я и подумал о чем то таком и возник данный вопрос.
Например если несколько курьеров будут писать в json новые данные по своих скутерах не будет ли проблем и не потеряю ли я какие то изменения.

Comment: @Oleksandr Strilchuk на самом деле не потеряете, если будете проверять ошибки записи в файловую систему. Делали с json чат(там частота записи, как понимете, в 10000 раз выше) - сначала были проблемы с записью: но потом предусмотрели ошибки - и как часы. Плюсы json: не тратится время на подключение к БД, читать можно вообще без бекенда: ajax на .txt файлы. Как раз обосновано там, где частые запросы, чтобы не грузить бек. Но в вашем случае - лучше БД, правда дольше возиться.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже сказали выше, лучше использовать БД. Добавлю свои 5 копеек, если нужно быстро и легко - MongoDB подойдёт как никак лучше, с NodeJS отлично работает, на других тоже вроде как поддерживается. А если хочется больше гибкости, выше скорость ответа от БД, то посоветую PostgreSQL.

Comment: Спасибо. На соседнем сайте так же советовали БД. Говорят что в целом можно попробовать php + mysql. Думаю за день - два осилю как на php читать и писать в базу. Для ноды насколько я понял нужно vps брать, а с php + mysql достаточно простого хостинга.

Comment: Для БД с парой таблиц размером в пару мегабайт - Mongo? Postgre? Вы это серьёзно? Да это самая задача для чего-нибудь простенького, вроде SQLite...

Comment: @Akina Потому и спрашивал что лучше. Я вообще думал в json хранить, но тут и на соседнем сайте сказали что будут проблемы с множественными запросами. С БД да и в целом с бекэндом не сталкивался еще ни разу. Понял что в данном случае самая простая связка это php + sqlite

Comment: @OleksandrStrilchuk *Я вообще думал в json хранить, но тут и на соседнем сайте сказали что будут проблемы с множественными запросами* Правильно сказали. Собственно, и тут тоже самое сказали - см. ответ S.H.